# How can I use my function from my .js file in my jade file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a function in my java script file that works and that looks like this:

```
function getSheetData(workbook, sheetNumber, cellName) {
 var workbook = xlsx.readFile(workbook);
 var sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[sheetNumber];
 var address_of_cell = cellName;
 var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheet_name];
 var desired_cell = worksheet[address_of_cell];
 var desired_value = desired_cell.v;
 return desired_value;
}
```

I want to use this function in my jade script, but I don't know how I would call it from my .js file or what format it should look like. I know that in java script I would do something like this:

```
var data = getSheetData('1234.xlsx', 0, 'A1');
 console.log(data);
```

But I don't know the syntax I would use in jade or how I would get it to use the function from my .js file.

Comment: You can't use function backend side in the client side. You should run the function in node and inject the results in the client view.

Comment: That's what I learned and ended up doing, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways.

1) You can pass result of your function as data to render:

```
// in js file
res.render('example.jade', {
     data: getSheetData('1234.xlsx', 0, 'A1')
})

// in jade file
div=data
```

2) Or you can share function for using in jade template:

```
// in main js file
global.getSheetData = function(workbook, sheetNumber, cellName){
      // your code
}
// in jade file
div=getSheetData('1234.xlsx', 0, 'A1')
```